# Caching sortable/filterable data in Redis

Tags: sorting, caching, redis

I have a variety of data that I've got cached in a standard Redis hashmap, and I've run into a situation where I need to respond to client requests for ordering and filtering. Order rankings for name, average rating, and number of reviews can change regularly (multiple times a minute, possibly). Can anyone advise me on a proper strategy for attacking this problem? Consider the following example to help understand what I'm looking for:

1. Client makes an API request to /api/v1/cookbooks?orderBy=name&limit=20&offset=0
2. I should respond with the first 20 entries, ordered by name

Strategies I've considered thus far:

- for each type of hashmap store (cookbooks, recipes, etc), creating a sorted set for each ordering scheme (alphabetical, average rating, etc) from a Postgres ORDER BY; then pulling out ZRANGE slices based on limit and offset
- storing ordering data directly into the JSON string data for each key.
- hitting postgres with an SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY *_*, and using the ids to pull directly from the hashmap store

Any additional thoughts or advice on how to best address this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as mentioned in a comment below [Sorted Sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) are a great way to implement sorting and filtering functionality in cache. Take the following example as an idea of how one might solve the issue of needing to order objects in a hash:

1. Given a hash called "movies" with the scheme of bucket:objectId -> object, which is a JSON string representation (read about "bucketing" your hashes for performance [here.](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs)
2. Create a sorted set called "movieRatings", where each member is an objectId from your "movies" hash, and its score is an average of all rating values (computed by the database). Just use a numerical representation of whatever you're trying to sort, and Redis gives you a lot of flexibility on how you can extract the slices you need.
3. This simple scheme has a lot of flexibility in what can be achieved - you simply ask your sorted set for a set of keys that fit your requirements, and look up those keys with HMGET from your "movies" hash. Two swift Redis calls, problem solved.
4. Rinse and repeat for whatever type of ordering you need, such as "number of reviews", "alphabetically", "actor count", etc. Filtering can also be done in this manner, but normal sets are probably quite sufficient for that purpose.

Comment: Your answer is misleading, Redis with filtering and ordering together is bad, simple example to illustrate: Give me movies of category 1, order by name, offset x, limit y.  If name is a sorted set (only structure to sort high volume efficiently) then limit and offset will include movies which are not of category 1 since that is a different set or sorted set.  Even without limit and offset, the result of querying a sorted set by score is not a redis set, so you can't do a further intersect efficiently.  But yes it works fine if you only have to order results or filter (not both).

Comment: Pierre, some of this intersection needs to be done in application code  - true. Get a list of id's sorted by name (in whatever array-like structure your language uses), then programmatically perform another call to Redis with those id's as the lookups to the set representing "category 1". Rinse and repeat. My answer isn't misleading, it's just not a comprehensive tutorial on how to implement sorting and filtering in Redis. Hardly worth a downvote, IMO.

Comment: Get a list of id's sorted by name will cause you to transfer your entire set of keys from redis, then transfer all of them back for a intersect with the category set and then do the limit and offset in your code.  What do you really gain from redis here?  Benchmark it against doing that only in your app code without Redis.  I've implemented this in Redis Lua scripting and it's still bad for high volumes.  Your answer makes it sound like filtering and sorting combined is good (supported) in Redis, when it forces you to retrieve entire sets from it.  Redis is legendary for other scenarios...

Comment: For your scenario it might not be slow if you don't have a lot of data.  What you ideally want is caching features from your ORM, most mature ones support it such as hibernate (java) or activerecord (ruby/rails), not sure if it's available in django.  Alternatively you could shard this table(s) out into another database, which seems like what you are trying to get from redis.

Comment: This answer is a good explanation of why it is bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205635/redis-filter-by-range-sort-and-return-10-first

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your needs. Each of your strategies could work.

- Your first approach of storing an auxiliary sorted set for each way
  you want to order is the best way to do this if you have a very big
  hash and/or you run your order queries frequently. This approach will
  require a lot of ram if your hash is big, but it will also scale well
  in terms of time complexity as your hash gets bigger and you start
  running order queries more frequently. On the other hand, it
  introduces complexity in your data structures, and feels like you're
  trying to use Redis for something a typical DB like Postgres, MySQL,
  or Mongo would be better at.
- Storing ordering data directly into your keys means you need to pull
  your entire hash every time you do an order query. Maybe that's not
  so bad if your hash is very small, or you don't do ordered queries very often, but this     won't scale at all.
- If you're already hitting Postgres to get keys, why not just store the values in Postgres as well. That would be much cheaper than hitting Postgres and then hitting Redis, and would have your code depend on fewer things. IMO, this is probably your best option and would work most naturally. Do this, unless you have some really good reason to not store values in Postgres, or some really big speed concerns, in which case go with your first strategy.

Comment: I agree with this. Looks like the OP is trying to use Redis where a relational DB is a better fit.

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to use Redis as an RMDBMS. I'm simply trying to minimize the amount of database access I do.

Comment: @patrickn I know it sucks to hear, and you know your situation better than the rest of us, but seriously consider whether the cost and complexity of continuing to use Redis here beats out scrapping Redis and just using Postgres by itself. I don't know your situation well enough to know whether that's true for you, but don't let the sunk cost you've invested in Redis so far keep you going down a non-optimal path if Redis actually increases complexity and/or hurts performance in your case.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not wanting to do any of the ordering calculations in Redis. I'm wanting to make order/average calculations once with Postgres and store them in the cache. This is a common use case for cache, the only extra bit I'm trying to do is use these cached calculations from Postgres and generate a key -> rank relationship that I can use to do quick ordering operations in memory.

Comment: After reviewing the Redis sorted set API In more detail, I think that this can be achieved with relative ease using the first scheme I considered. If it does indeed work as I suspect it will, I will come back and post what I did as a proper answer.